# Faucet hose doesn't fit water input in sink - Can I buy an adapter?

Tags: plumbing, water, sink

I just bought a new faucet, and when I try to connect the hose that comes with it into the existing water supply, it doesn't fit. The diameter of the hose (below) [image: diameter of the hose] is different than the diameter of the water supply (below) [image: water supply].

What type of adapter and size do I need in order to connect these two?

Comment: Take the old one to your big box store and see if they have a mate.

Comment: Do the threads fit together if you take the rubber gasket and strainer out of the hose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to guess the size from the picture, but

Shut-off valves (the wall part) come with different-sized outlet ports. The two most common are 3/8- and 1/2-inch compression or male pipe thread. Faucets (the hose) most have 1/2-inch male pipe thread connectors. The hoses that connect the valves to the faucet have a 1/2-inch diameter and come in various lengths and with various configurations of 3/8- and 1/2-inch female connectors.

It looks like you need male to male adapter, from 1/2 inch to 3/8 inch